# Excel Data Validation List dependent on Multiple Tables

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to find a way to do dynamic data validation from a drop down list from information in different tables. A simplified version of my tables are:

[image]

From left to right they are Tables: **List1, List2, List3, Relations**

On a separate workbook I am want to have a drop down list so that you can select the appropriate inputs.

So the first cell I set it up to give you the list from the **List1** Table.

Now comes my issue. The second cell I want to pull all the distinct values from the **Relations** table.
*SQL would be something like:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT L2 FROM Relations WHERE L1=3;
```

Then the third cell would be similar but depended on the selection from the first 2 cells.

*SQL would be something like:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT L3 FROM Relations WHERE L1=3 AND L2=0;
```

Any Ideas or thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I have found a way to do this (that uses helper columns).  Are your "dropdown lists" data validation lists or combo boxes inserted into the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a way to do this using helper columns.  That's not ideal and hopefully someone else posts an answer that can do it with just a single formula.  In the meantime you can use this.

This answer assumes that you are using data validation for your lists.  It assumes that the data in your screenshot is on Sheet1 and the cells with data valiedation for List 1, List 2, List 3 and Order are in Sheet2!B1:B4 respectively.

You don't need your List1, List2 and List3, you can get everything from the relations table.  If you do get everything from the Relations table you only need to update one table.

Getting a list in Sheet2!B1 from Relations of distinct values for List 1:

1. On Sheet1 in column S select S2:S200 and while they are all selected enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(($M$2:$M$200<>""),$M$2:$M$200,"")
   ```
2. In T2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(SUM(IF(S2=T$1:T1,1,0)),"",S2)
   ```
3. Copy T2 into T3:T200
4. In U2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(T$2:T$200, SMALL(IF(T$2:T$200="", "", ROW(T$2:T$200)-MIN(ROW(T$2:T$200))+1), ROW($A1))), "")
   ```
5. Copy U2 into U3:U200
6. Define the name List1 to be this:

   ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$U$2:$U$200,0,0,200-1-COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$U$2:$U$200),1)
   ```
7. Finally change the Data Validation on Sheet2!B1 to:

   ```
   =List1
   ```

Getting a list in Sheet2!B2 from Relations of distinct values for List 2 filtering by Sheet2!B1:

1. On Sheet1 in column W select W2:W200 and while they are all selected enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(($M$2:$M$200=Sheet2!$B$1),$N$2:$N$200,"")
   ```
2. In X2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(SUM(IF(W2=X$1:X1,1,0)),"",W2)
   ```
3. Copy X2 into X3:X200
4. In Y2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(X$2:X$200, SMALL(IF(X$2:X$200="", "", ROW(X$2:X$200)-MIN(ROW(X$2:X$200))+1), ROW($A1))), "")
   ```
5. Copy Y2 into Y3:Y200
6. Define the name List2 to be this:

   ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$Y$2:$Y$200,0,0,200-1-COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$Y$2:$Y$200),1)
   ```
7. Finally change the Data Validation on Sheet2!B2 to:

   ```
   =List2
   ```

Getting a list in Sheet2!B3 from Relations of distinct values for List 3 filtering by Sheet2!B1 and Sheet2!B2:

1. On Sheet1 in column AA select AA2:AA200 and while they are all selected enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(($M$2:$M$200=Sheet2!$B$1)*($N$2:$N$200=Sheet2!$B$2),$O$2:$O$200,"")
   ```
2. In AB2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(SUM(IF(AA2=AB$1:AB1,1,0)),"",AA2)
   ```
3. Copy AB2 into AB3:AB200
4. In AC2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(AB$2:AB$200, SMALL(IF(AB$2:AB$200="", "", ROW(AB$2:AB$200)-MIN(ROW(AB$2:AB$200))+1), ROW($A1))), "")
   ```
5. Copy AC2 into AC3:AC200
6. Define the name List3 to be this:

   ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AC$2:$AC$200,0,0,200-1-COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$AC$2:$AC$200),1)
   ```
7. Finally change the Data Validation on Sheet2!B3 to:

   ```
   =List3
   ```

Getting a list in Sheet2!B4 from Relations of distinct values for Order filtering by Sheet2!B1, Sheet2!B2 and Sheet2!B3:

1. On Sheet1 in column AE select AE2:AE200 and while they are all selected enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(($M$2:$M$200=Sheet2!$B$1)*($N$2:$N$200=Sheet2!$B$2)*($O$2:$O$200=Sheet2!$B$3),$Q$2:$Q$200,"")
   ```
2. In AF2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IF(SUM(IF(AE2=AF$1:AF1,1,0)),"",AE2)
   ```
3. Copy AF2 into AF3:AF200
4. In AG2 enter this array formula (Make sure you hit Shift Control Enter instead of Enter after you type it in):

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(AF$2:AF$200, SMALL(IF(AF$2:AF$200="", "", ROW(AF$2:AF$200)-MIN(ROW(AF$2:AF$200))+1), ROW($A1))), "")
   ```
5. Copy AG2 into AG3:AG200
6. Define the name Order to be this:

   ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$AG$2:$AG$200,0,0,200-1-COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$AG$2:$AG$200),1)
   ```
7. Finally change the Data Validation on Sheet2!B4 to:

   ```
   =Order
   ```

If I can figure out somewhere to upload my sample spreadsheet I will edit the answer with a link...